# Strange behavior with actions, local variables and garbage collection in MVVM light Messenger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, garbage-collection, mvvm-light

I am having a really strange problem with the `Messenger` system in MVVM Light. It's hard to explain, so here is small program that demonstrates the issue:

```
using System;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prog = new Program();
            var recipient = new object();

            prog.RegisterMessageA(recipient);
            prog.RegisterMessageB(recipient);

            prog.SendMessage("First Message");
            GC.Collect();
            prog.SendMessage("Second Message");
        }

        public void RegisterMessageA(object target)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register(this, (Message msg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " recieved by A");
                var x = target;
            });
        }

        public void RegisterMessageB(object target)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register(this, (Message msg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by B");
            });
        }

        public void SendMessage(string name)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(new Message { Name = name });
        }

        class Message
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run the application, this is the console output:

```
First Message recieved by A
First Message received by B
Second Message received by B
```

As you can see, the second message is never received by recipient A. However, the only difference between B and A is one line: the statement `var x = target;`. If you remove this line, `A` receives the second message.

Also, if you remove `GC.Collect();` then `A` receives the second message. However, this only hides the issue, as in a real program the garbage collector will automatically run eventually.

Why is this happening? I assume that somehow, if the recipient action refers to a variable from it's containing method scope, it ties the action's lifetime to that scope so that once out of the scope it can be garbage collected. I don't understand why this is at all. I also don't understand why actions that do not reference variables from the scope they are defined in do not have this problem.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: By the way, I have a previous question from when I first encountered this problem. It shows a real world use case rather than an abstract example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536399/mvvm-light-message-recipient-action-being-garbage-collected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I now understand why it's happening (I believe, anyway). I've reproduced it in a shorter form which *doesn't* use lambda expressions, and then I'll explain why the lambdas are important.

```
using System;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Receiver r1 = new Receiver("r1");
        Receiver r2 = new Receiver("r2");
        var recipient = new object();

        Messenger.Default.Register<object>(recipient, r1).ShowMessage;
        Messenger.Default.Register<object>(recipient, r2).ShowMessage;

        GC.Collect();
        Messenger.Default.Send(recipient, null);
        // Uncomment one of these to see the relevant message...
        // GC.KeepAlive(r1);
        // GC.KeepAlive(r2);
    }
}

class Receiver
{
    private string name;

    public Receiver(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void ShowMessage(object message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("message received by {0}", name);
    }
}
```

Basically, the messenger only keeps a *weak reference* to the message handler. (Also to the recipient, but that's not a problem here.) More specifically, it appears to have a weak reference to the handler's *target* object. It doesn't seem to care about the delegate object itself, but the target is important. So in the above code, when you keep a `Receiver`
object alive, the delegate which has that object as a target is still used. However, when the target is allowed to be garbage collected, the handler using that object is not used.

Now let's look at your two handler:

```
public void RegisterMessageA(object target)
{
    Messenger.Default.Register(target, (Message msg) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by A");
        var x = target;
    });
}
```

This lambda expression *captures* the `target` parameter. In order to capture it, the compiler generates a new class - so `RegisterMessageA` is effectively:

```
public void RegisterMessageA(object target)
{
    GeneratedClass x = new GeneratedClass();
    x.target = target;
    Messenger.Default.Register(x.target, x.Method);
}

private class GeneratedClass
{
    public object target;

    public void Method(Message msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by A");
        var x = target;
    }
}
```

Now, there's nothing other than the delegate which keeps that instance of `GeneratedClass` alive. Compare that with your second handler:

```
public void RegisterMessageB(object target)
{
    Messenger.Default.Register(target, (Message msg) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by B");
    });
}
```

Here, there are no captured variables, so the compiler generates code a bit like this:

```
public void RegisterMessageB(object target)
{
    Messenger.Default.Register(target, RegisterMessageB_Lambda);
}

private static void RegisterMessageB_Lambda(Message msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by B");
}
```

Here it's a *static* method, so there's no delegate target at all. If the delegate captured `this`, it would be generated as an instance method. But the important point is that there's no need to generate an extra class... so there's nothing to be garbage collected.

I haven't looked into exactly how MvvmLight is doing this - whether it's *just* got a weak reference to the delegate, and that the CLR is treating that in some special way, or whether MvvmLight is separating the target from the delegate itself. Either way, I hope that explains the behaviour you're seeing. In terms of how to fix whatever problem you're seeing with *real* code - basically you'll need to make sure you keep a strong reference to whatever delegate target you need.

EDIT: Okay, it looks like it's now due to [`WeakActionGeneric`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Helpers/WeakActionGeneric.cs) and its base class [`WeakAction`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Helpers/WeakAction.cs). I don't know whether this behaviour is the *expected* behaviour (by the author), but that's the code responsible :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had not really thought before about what the compiler is doing with lambda functions.

Comment: @Oliver: Glad it helped. I can see it being a pretty annoying behaviour, mind you...

Comment: @Oliver: See my edit at the bottom - I've tracked down the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try fiddling with the implementation here to see if I can fix this problem. Using lambda functions with variable capture is very convenient, and I don't want to have to avoid that.

Comment: @Oliver: Yup. You might want to post an issue on the MvvmLight site referring to this question...

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the behavior of this program is really strange.

I tried it myself and as you already figured out the problem is somehow related to this line:

```
var x = target;
```

I have no idea why this line causes any trouble but you might consider this workaround:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prog = new Program();
            var recipient = new object();

            prog.RegisterMessageA(recipient);
            prog.RegisterMessageB(recipient);

            prog.SendMessage("First Message");
            GC.Collect();
            prog.SendMessage("Second Message");
        }

        public void RegisterMessageA(object target)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register(target, (Message msg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by A");
                var x = msg.Target;
            });
        }

        public void RegisterMessageB(object target)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register(target, (Message msg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Name + " received by B");
            });
        }

        public void SendMessage(string name)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(new Message { Name = name });
        }

        class Message : MessageBase //part of the MVVM Light framework
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

MessageBase is a class from the MVVM Light Framework which offers the possibility to retrieve the target from the message itself.

But I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Thanks for the input. I didn't know about MessageBase, and this workaround should work in the particular case that brought the issue to my attention. I'm going to leave this question open to see if anyone knows why this is occurring, though.

Comment: Whoops, this fix doesn't work for me, unfortunately. I had hoped that `Target` was automatically set by MVVM Light, but this doesn't seem to be the case - it's just a property that the implementing application can use. In the example above, `msg.Target` is null.

Comment: I was assuming the same! I tried something else, would you mind having a look? http://tny.cz/1068081b

Comment: Yes, I think something like this would work. However, it's not suitable in my case (a viewmodel telling its view to close) as the sender does not hold a reference to the recipient. In the end, I have changed the code around so that it does not use an anonymous function. I hope someone can clarify what is causing this issue, though.