# mvvmlight messenger strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a strange behavior in my project. I use MvvmLight messenger to notify different parts of my UI to update.

```
   public EntryViewModel(MenuViewModel menuVM, Entry item)
    {
        this._menuVM = menuVM;
        OpenDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenDetailsInMainWindow);
        BackCommand = new RelayCommand(Back);

        this._entry = item;
        Refresh(); 

        Messenger.Default.Register<CardUpdateMessage>(this, this._entry.Id, msg => Refresh(); );   
 }
```

and send with

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new CardUpdateMessage(id), id);
```

when I see Messenger content after registration it contains about 400 registered actions of CardUpdateMessage, but when I call send none of them fires. 
By the way, similar code with single registered object per Message type work as I expect. What is the cause of this problem?

**Update**: I have made some research with debugger and found that in file https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)/Messaging/Messenger.cs method SendToList is fired and in its inner loop WeakAction is fired, but Refresh method is not run. Does it something I haven't suspected with WeakAction?

**Solution**: I have found the case of this issue. It's NOT ALLOWED to use anonimous function in Messenger.Register due to unexpected behavior. 
just `Messenger.Default.Register(this, this._entry.Id, Refresh);` and
`private void Refresh(CardUpdateMessage msg) ...`

**External reference**: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7640

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but you shouldn't edit that into your question.  Just add an answer below with what you found, and after the required waiting period, you can select it as correct and close this out.  It may seem odd, but that's how we do it here.

Comment: @Will ok, I have write my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7640 and this
[Strange behavior with actions, local variables and garbage collection in MVVM light Messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613828/strange-behavior-with-actions-local-variables-and-garbage-collection-in-mvvm-li)

Solution in short words - do no use lambdas in Messenger.Default.Register, because the can behave not as you expected.

Comment: 3 years later the link 1st is broken, unfortunately.