# MvvmLight Messenger not triggering when var from outside is used

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have a simple Message sender (the "RecordStore"), that sends that Message:

```
public class RecordStoreUpdatedMessage
{
    public BaseModel Model { get; set; }

    public RecordStoreUpdatedMessage(BaseModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }
}

// somewhere in RecordStore:
var item = new BaseModel();
Messenger.Default.Send(new RecordStoreUpdatedMessage(item));
```

Then I got a receiver, that registers a callback to this Message:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<RecordStoreUpdatedMessage>(this, msg => {
                Debug.WriteLine("DataTreeItemViewModel: cought RecordStoreUpdatedMessage");
                //Debug.WriteLine("and the current item is " + anything);
});
```

Til there all is good, the Debug.WriteLine fires, I can get everything from RecordStoreUpdateMassage via 'msg'.

**BUT**

as soon as I introduce *and use* a local var (no matter what) in the receiver's  callback none of the `Debug.WriteLines` fire anymore (I need that local var to check if the Updated Record really affects me or if I just can ignore it):

```
string anything = "Test";
Messenger.Default.Register<RecordStoreUpdatedMessage>(this, msg => {
                Debug.WriteLine("DataTreeItemViewModel: cought RecordStoreUpdatedMessage");
                Debug.WriteLine("and the current item is " + anything);
});
```

Result: nothing. No Error, no Debug.WriteLine.

*Versions:*
[mvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight) 5.4.1.1
.Net 4.6.1
Maybe relevant: sender and receiver live in 2 different projects/assemblies

I've studies several questions like [Strange behavior with actions, local variables and garbage collection in MVVM light Messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613828/strange-behavior-with-actions-local-variables-and-garbage-collection-in-mvvm-li) and [mvvmlight messenger strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911423/mvvmlight-messenger-strange-behaviour), but didn't find one that addresses that tiny difference of using a local var.

Nearly forgot to ask a specific question...:
Why is using a local var hindering the Messenger to fire the callback? What can I do to be able to use a local var in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Making the callback not a lambda, but a reference to a method did th trick:

```
// in Constructor
Messenger.Default.Register<JeffData.Messages.RecordStoreUpdatedMessage>(this, UpdateItem);

private void UpdateItem(JeffData.Messages.RecordStoreUpdatedMessage recordStoreUpdatedMessage)
{
    // here I can use ModelType now (a property of this class)
    if (recordStoreUpdatedMessage.Model.GetType() == ModelType && recordStoreUpdatedMessage.Model.Id == Model.Id)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DataTreeItemViewModel: cought RecordStoreUpdatedMessage with item: " + recordStoreUpdatedMessage.Model.GetType().ToString());
        Model = recordStoreUpdatedMessage.Model;
    }
}
```

Still: I could understand that a local var cannot be used in a callback becouse of scope and GC issues. But not triggering the callback at all is strange...if not a bug.